# Laravel - transfer data to another DB

Tags: laravel

I have such a problem with Laravel.
I write different data during user registration in several tables.
Then when the user logs in to their account, they have to pay the amount.
The data that the user has filled in and already exists in the database must then be transferred to another database.

The problem is this:
When transferring data to another database it writes to the database several times.
I could not figure out how to solve the problem.

Here is code:

```php
$visitor = DB::table('Visitor')->where('PaymentId', $res['payId'])->first();
    
User::where('IdVisitor', $visitor->IdVisitor)->update(['isPaid' => 1]);
    
DB::connection('sqlsrv2')->table('Visitor')->insert([
    'Visitor' => $visitor->Visitor,
    'CardNumber' => $visitor->$CardNumber,
    'Address' => $visitor->Address,
    'Phone' => $visitor->Phone,
    'Sagad' => $visitor->Sagad,
    'MobilePhone' => $visitor->MobilePhone,
    'Mail' => $visitor->Mail,
    'Shen' => $visitor->Shen,
    'Active' => 1,
    'IdOrgT' => 1,
    'IdCountry' => $visitor->IdCountry,
    'FG' => 1,
    'Dgg' => 1,
    'IdVatType' => 0,
    'Discount' => 0,
    'AllowVali' => 0,
    'DataBirth' => $visitor->DataBirth,
    'UN' => 'Web',
    'CD' => $org->CD,
    'Comment' => $visitor->Comment,
    'Color' => 0,
    'IdOrgLanguage' => 1,
    'IdSex' => $visitor->IdSex,
    'OrgImage' => 1,
    'IdTituli' => 1,
    'IdFasiCategory' => 1,
    'CD11' => $visitor->CD11
]);
    
$visit = DB::table('Visit')->where('IdVisitor', $visitor->IdVisitor)->first();
    
DB::connection('sqlsrv2')->table('Visit')->insert([
    'Data' => $visit->Date,
    'DataEnd' => $visit->DateEnd,
    'IdVisitT' => 1,
    'IdRoom' => 0,
    'IdVisitor' => $visitor->IdVisitor,
    'IdCompany' => 163,
    'IdVisitStatus' => 1,
    'IdGaqiravebaT' => 1,
    'Zedd' => '100000',
    'GroupNum' => '',
    'IsInvoicePrinted' => 0,
    'IsReservation' => 1,
    'IsConfirmed' => 1,
    'IsSpecFasi' => 0,
    'SpecFasi' => 0.00,
    'IdValuta' => 3,
    'Kursi' => $visit->Kursi,
    'Shen' => $visit->Shen,
    'RaodAdult' => $visit->RaodAdult,
    'RaodChild' => $visit->RaodChild,
    'RoomFasi' => $visit->RoomFasi,
    'CheckIn' => 0,
    'CheckOut' => 0,
    'CheckInFasi' => 0.00,
    'CheckOutfasi' => 0.00,
    'VisitFasi' => $visit->VisitFasi,
    'UN' => 'Web',
    'CD' => $visit->CD,
    'CD1' => $visit->CD1,
    'PaidAll' => 1,
    'NoPost' => 1,
    'ExtraBed' => 0,
    'KidsBed' => 0,
    'KidsManej' => 0,
    'MoveRoom' => '0',
    'IdAgenti' => 1,
    'NoShow' => 0
]);
```

thanks.

Comment: Your code shouldn't insert multiple copies into either the Visitor or Visit tables. Are you sure it's not being called more than once? Also, if there are constraints on your data, you could use them to prevent duplicate inserts. For example, if a visitor is allowed only one visit per day, you could do something like Visit::updateOrCreate(['IdVisitor'=>$visitor->IdVisitor,'Data'=>$visit->Date],[....])

Comment: Yes, I'm surprised too. When the responce is returned from the bank server after payment if($ res ['status'] == 'Succeeded') {...}
After that the data is added six times.
I don't understand why

I can not use Eloquent because the database already exists and I can not add a model

Comment: I think the code needs more details to know why it's being called 6 times. You *can* add an eloquent model for an existing database, even if it's not using the default connection but I don't think that would be particularly helpful here. As mankowitz suggested, using updateOrCreate could work.